# 401 Auth error with apps script connecting to 3rd party API

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, jira-rest-api

I am beating my head up trying to get this to work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have tested the auth in Insomnia and Postman and its working fine but not with apps script. I am getting a "401 Authorization Required" response.

```
function myFunction() {
    var url = "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/project/MYPROJECT";
    var token = "THISISATOKEN";

    var headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+ token,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    var options = {
        "method" : "get",
        "headers" : headers 
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);

    Logger.log(response);
```

Comment: Try declaring content type in options via the 'contentType' property. Otherwise, it defaults to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. options["contentType"] = 'application/json'.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the specification of the API from your question, in your script, ``headers`` is declared in ``options``. But ``options`` is not used at ``var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers)``. How about modifying to ``var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)``? If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, you were absolutely right.... I was having other issues before using the options so I switched to calling the headers instead. 

That sir solved my problem :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.